# How retrieve specific field from multi fielded dropdown list box in ASP.NET

Tags: html, asp.net

I have a database with rows:

```
tname, serviceno, time, duration, f1,f2,f3,f4,
cost, b1, b2, b3, fromp, topl
```

I used the database in a drop down list box with multiple fields in the sigle column of drop down list box look like below:

```
shocker travels---111---9:00 AM to 5:00 PM---|2+2|hitech push back|AC|LCD---Rs:350

pavan travels---222---11:30 AM to 5:00 PM---|2+2|hitech push back|NON AC|LCD---Rs:450

jaya travels---333---10:45 AM to 4:00 PM---|2+2|hitech push back|AC|LCD---Rs:550
```

To do that I used this code

```
public partial class searchbus : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
    string str;
    SqlCommand com;
    SqlDataAdapter sqlda;
    DataSet ds;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS);
            SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(CS);
            con.Open();
            con1.Open();
            str = "select * from busdetailstable where fromp like'" + TextBox1.Text + "%' and topl like '" + TextBox2.Text + "%'";
            com = new SqlCommand(str, con);
            sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
            ds = new DataSet();
            sqlda.Fill(ds, "busdetailstable");
            for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {   
               DropDownList1.Items.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["tname"] + "----" +ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["serviceno"]+"-----" +ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["time"] + "  to  " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["duration"] + "----|" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["f1"] + "|" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["f2"] + "|" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["f3"] + "|" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["f4"] + "|-------- Rs  :" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["cost"].ToString());
               Session["travels"] = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();      
            }
            con.Close();
    }
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("boarding.aspx");
    }
```

However, I want to print serviceno in the drop down list box's selected tname in another page's label control.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please provide a sample code describing your problem and efforts!

Comment: You want to show the ddl's Selecteditem to another pages label. Right?

Comment: i don't want all data in ddl selected item., i want only specific data in ddl because in ddl every column has some fields from database. in that i want 222(serviceno) only.

Comment: I've corrected the formatting of your question to make it easier to read.

Comment: Thank you soo much @ Wai Ha Lee